# Add multiple attachments to gmail

Tags: google-apps-script, attachment, google-sheets

I am using a Google spreadsheet and wish to send multiple attachments to our customers, no matter how I format the code it is either rejected or only one attachment is sent, can anyone help with this please

```
function emailcustomer() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("email to customer")  
var subject = sheet.getRange("B2").getValue()
var content = sheet.getRange("A12").getValue()
var doc1 = sheet.getRange("d28").getValue()
var doc2 = sheet.getRange("d29").getValue()   
var file1 = DocsList.getFileById(doc1);  
var file2 = DocsList.getFileById(doc2); 
  GmailApp.sendEmail("alex.shaw94@gmail.com",subject,content,{attachments:file1 file2});
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try something like this :

```
var myFiles = [{fileName:"doc1", content:file1}, {fileName:"doc2", content:file2}]
GmailApp.sendEmail("alex.shaw94@gmail.com", subject,content, {attachments: myFiles});
```

Also, maybe this can help : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_gmailapp#sendEmail

Comment: I did try your first suggestion but I get this message "Attachment content not recognized as string or binary"

Comment: Thanks for the tip I got it to work in the end after playing around with several ideas by using the following code var myFiles = [file1,file2]  
GmailApp.sendEmail("alex.shaw94@gmail.com",subject,content,{attachments:myFiles});

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the mimetype of the attachment and then add it to your array:

```
var attachments = [];
attachments.push(file.getAs(MimeType.PDF));
GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body,{
     attachments: attachments,
    });
```