# GmailApp.createDraft incorrectly creates multiple copies of only 1 attachment when i try to send multiple attachments

Tags: google-apps-script

I have to send emails with multiple pdfs using GAS. These PDFs are generated from google docs and encrypted with a function i made.

When i use GmailApp.sendEmail() there are no problems. The receiver receives the email with the different attachments.

When i use GmailApp.createDraft() and then manually hit send on Gmail, the receiver only receives multiple copies of the first attachment.

idsarray is an array of Google Docs ids.

encryptpdf() is a function I made that returns a blob of the encrypted pdf

body is a string with the html of the email body

```
for( var i = 0 ; i < idsarray.length ; i++) {

var pdfname = DriveApp.getFileById( idsarray[i]).getName() ;
var blob = encryptpdf(idsarray[i], pdfname , email )

if (i == 0 ) { var docblob = [blob] ; } else{ docblob.push(blob);}
}}
```

i use the following to send the email and it works with no problem. The receiver receives the email with the multiple attachments.

```
GmailApp.sendEmail( email , "docs" , "" , {
    attachments: docblob ,
    htmlBody: body   
});
```

Sometimes I need to create a draft first so someone else can change the body of the email. It shows fine in our side. Then he sends it from his gmail. Then the receiver receives the email with multiple copies of only the first attachment. I use the following:

```
GmailApp.createDraft( email , "" , "" , {
    attachments: docblob });
```

Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: Have you tried changing your format of adding attachments? Please refer to the ff previous SO posts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779231/add-multiple-attachments-to-gmail

Comment: Yes i have tried. I should clarify that when i create the draft in my mail client it shows just fine with all attachments. When i send it it shows just fine in my side, but the receiver of the email only sees the first attachment multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I finally tracked down the error. It seems its a mix of bugs in GAS and the gmail app

When using GmailApp.createDraft if the receiver is using the gmail app then all the attachments will be identical when trying to open it. If the receiver tries to save them to google drive then it saves them correctly.

In other apps it works as expected.